# Must I use execSQL for update with expression when working with SQLite on Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

So my question is this.

**In the existing android framework is there any way to perform an UPDATE where the SET value is an *expression* using [ContentValues](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html)?**

Now what I want to achieve is an SQL update where one column is updated to the value of two other columns like so:

```
UPDATE myTable SET columnA = columnB + columnC WHERE rowId = 5
```

This works, no problem. However I can't see any way of doing this with ContentValues and the android documentation [explicitly says](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D)):

> void  execSQL(String sql, Object[] bindArgs)
>
> Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE.
>
> ...
>
> For UPDATE statements, use any of the following instead.
>
> update(String, ContentValues, String, String[])
>
> updateWithOnConflict(String, ContentValues, String, String[], int)

So can it be done with the existing update methods or am I going to have to ignore the docs and go ahead with execSQL?

Comment: I have no idea why the documentation says that. Looking at [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.java), since they use bind arguments for everything, I do not see how you could use your desired expression.

Comment: As usual once I'd given up looking at the problem and posted the question here I found a potential solution in SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement. I will update if this works.

Comment: Use `rawQuery()` for queries (SELECTs) and `execSQL()` for commands (anything else).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I'll leave this here for anyone that is as blind as me and misses the obvious:

You can go fancy and use [SQliteDatabase.compileStatement(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#compileStatement(java.lang.String)) or as 
Bob Malooga so kindly pointed out use [SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery (String, String[])](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]))